# Find blank pages from pdf files?

Tags: pdf

We have requirement to find if there is any blank/empty pages in a PDF files.
Actually there are 4 million PDF files which needs to be validated for above condition and also there will be 10k-12k pages in a PDF. Hence need a script to automate this work.

Comment: What OS / environment / script language? This question is too broad. Also, what things did you try yourself?

Comment: we will have to validate PDF files in Windows OS. I have not tried any scripting language yet. I am still trying to find best way to do my requirement.

Comment: It's a broad requirement but I would convert the pages with ghostscrip, or any other rasterizer, to an image and than would check if the page had any pixel on. To check the image use powershell by importing the System.Drawing assembly.

Comment: There is also software that already does this. Search for preflight software, you'll find applications such as callas pdfToolbox (I'm affiliated with this tool) and PitStop. Checking for empty pages is a common thing in graphic arts (you want to avoid people sending in empty PDF files when they're supplying advertisements for example).

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestion. But I need a scripting language to do the same

Comment: is there any other way to do it via scripting language

Answer (score 0):

You could check the size of each page. It is the easiest solution I have found so far:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader, PdfFileMerger

output = PdfFileWriter()
tempoutput = PdfFileWriter()
input1 = PdfFileReader(open("document4.pdf", "rb"))

print ("document4.pdf has %d pages." % input1.getNumPages())
numPages1=input1.getNumPages()


def getSize(filename):
    st = os.stat(filename)
    return st.st_size

for i in range(numPages1):
    canv1 = Canvas("paginatemporal.pdf")
    canv1.showPage()
    canv1.save()
    archivotemp=open("paginatemporal.pdf", "rb")
    temporal = PdfFileReader(archivotemp)
    page=input1.getPage(i)
    page.mergePage(temporal.getPage(0))
    tempoutput.addPage(page)
    outputStreamTemp = open("paginasize.pdf", "wb")
    tempoutput.write(outputStreamTemp)
    page=input1.getPage(i)
    pdfsize1= getSize("paginasize.pdf")
    if pdfsize1<60000:
        print("Page number " + str(i+1) +" is blank.")
    elif pdfsize1>=60000:
        print("Page number "+ str(i+1) + " is not blank.")
    print(pdfsize1)

    archivotemp.close()
    outputStreamTemp.close()
    os.remove("paginatemporal.pdf")
    os.remove("paginasize.pdf")
    tempoutput = PdfFileWriter()
```

I was just trying somethings out, so it is not finished, I needed to find each page because I have to add the label :"No text" on blank pages and put sequential page numbers on every page of each topic (which can have multiple files). That is the reason I am using canvas and page merge.

I used too many temp files, but will clean the code soon.

Hope this helps you. It is in Python 3. The number 60,000 is the size I put because all blank pages on my files were less than 50,000 and all pages that had information were over 100,000, but it could change if your files are different. Try it with some of them and adjust the number to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick comes with a compare program that will compare images, or PDF pages (if Ghostscript is installed for it to use).

You could create a blank PDF page and use compare to compare it against each PDF page of each file.

You can use bindings for a scripting language (such as either the imagemagick or the wand bindings for python), and then all you need to know is the number of pages per PDF.  If you're using Python, either PyPDF2 or pdfrw (disclaimer: I am the author) could give you this information.

I have never compared against a blank page, so I will note that you might need the correct size blank page for each page of every document.  You could cache these to do the comparison.  Either PyPDF2 or pdfrw can figure these page sizes out, as well.